# How can I implement JMS MessageListener?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, message-queue

I tried to implement MessageListener, but it dosen't work, but when I use MessageListner, it doesn't work. So what should I do that MessageListener starts working, I'm using jboss 4.02.

```
recv.receive(); // This works

recv.setMessageListener(new ExListener()); // This doesn't work

    public static class ExListener 
    implements MessageListener
    {
        public void onMessage(Message msg)
        {
            TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
            try {
                System.out.println("onMessage, recv text="+tm.getText());
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide information on what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: With first example I get messages and I can sysout them, but in second example I get no messages, because there are no prints to sysout

Answer (score 4):

Did you remember to call connection.start()? I guess you must have had that for the receive() method to work, but perhaps you accidentally deleted it when you changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented on the Jboss server by the use of message driven beans which is probably the best way to do it and ofcourse a more lightweight option is to create a jmsListener in Spring by implementing the MessageListener http://bit.ly/epVSmS

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the class that registers the listener has ended and the listener object goes out of existence. You should keep the object live and running to receive the message.